# When are Bone Charms found during a mission determined?

Tags: dishonored

There are a total of 45 unique Bone Charms in **Dishonored**, but far fewer of them are found in any given play though. This is because each charm found is *randomly* selected from the complete list. What stinks though, is that Bone Charms usefulness varies *wildly*. Some, like the .5 second chokehold are massive boosts. Others, like Albino, seem to be totally useless.

If I were an... ahem-*Dishonorable* gamer, and interested in savescumming for better Bone Charms, from what point would I have to reload? Is it determined at Mission Start, at entry to the 'zone' where the Charm is located, when it's picked up, or at some other point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you won't have much luck scumming.

According to the Dishonored wiki,

> Charms spawn randomly. They are chosen when the level is loaded so reloading right before obtaining one will always yeild the same charm.

However, **there are at least two charms that are scummable.  The first, in the vice behind the High Overseer's Office, is determined when the vice is opened.  The second is the one in Daud's pouch.**  I've tried both of these and confirmed them.

Answer (score 0):

On mission 3 I was able to scum the bone charm found with the weepers in the cage in the distillery and also the one found on the wall in the golden cat each case I saved before I went into to the respective areas and kept reloading form there. This method took a long time but it was worth it I think.

Answer (score -3):

The charms are determined at the beginning of each playthrough, so if you want different charms you have to start a new game

Comment: This is not true at all. i have just gotten 2 different bonecharms at the same spot by quicksaving before i entered the area

Comment: @SergeBekenkamp - This indicates random behavior.  Since there is no proof from Rag that charms are created when you start a new game, i have to downvote this, proof is always good.

Comment: I just tried quicksaving and loading and got the same charm. I suppose we'd need to do some more dedicated testing.

Comment: @kyte did you quicksave before entering the area(map) or just before picking it up? Also ill have another look at it tomorrow and see what i come up with

Comment: Just did some testing. Normal save/loads do reset Bone Charms, while quicksaves don't. Since quicksaves are a PC thing and the devs apparently forgot about PC-specific features (for example, the hints don't acknowledge such things as the quickbar or the R/T buttons for drinking potions without accessing the quickwheel), it wouldn't be surprising if that also applied to quickloading.